# configuring php .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, server, apache2

I don't know much on how htaccess configuration works and I'm struggling to write a configuration that takes care of two scenarios below:-

1. server php pages request without .php extension
2. rewrite the url without redirecting, for instance, rewrite
   https://example.com/success/24 to https://example.com?response=success&id=24

-Taking care of the first scenario is straight forward but on trying to accommodate the second scenario I'm messing with the first configuration. The code i'm using in the .htaccess file is as follows:-

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```

Please someone assist on how I should accommodate the two use scenarios.

Comment: Please give us a proper problem description, in what way exactly this is not working.

Comment: The server is not able to serve any other page except the index page. Trying to navigate to any other page i'm getting not found

Answer (score 0):

For the first scenario

this is code for .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Comment: Thanks. How about incorporating the second scenario?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]




You can take the last two lines from the answer.